# How to open Tortoise SVN commit UI from Command prompt

Tags: tortoisesvn

I need to open the Tortoise SVN commit window from command prompt, and not be right clicking on the windows explorer.

What is the command to do it?

Comment: See https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html